# Possible to shell out from a cloudflare worker?

Tags: cloudflare, serverless-architecture, cloudflare-workers

In google cloud functions it is easy to shell out and even run native linux binaries using `child_process.execSync(command)`, which is how I was able to get `gcf.cr` to run native crystal code in google cloud functions.

Playing around with Cloudflare Workers at a glance this doesn't seem to be possible as it seems I can't even do `require('child_process');`.

Does Cloudflare Workers not allow shelling out? If so then it's usefulness greatly diminishes for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudflare Workers runs on top of V8 isolates, not a process-level container. This has several advantages, like near-instant cold starts, but means it's not possible to run arbitrary binaries.

What type of application are you hoping to run? Is it something which can be compiled to WebAssembly?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Zack's good answer: Cloudflare Workers currently allow HTTP outbound and that's about it.

If you need anything more than that (ex: using child processes, or TCP connections), it isn't currently possible.